# Duplicate keys in LinkedHashMap

Tags: android, linkedhashmap

Suppose I have `LinkedhashMap<String, List> myLHM = new LinkedHashMap<>()`

Values of `myLHM` :

```
<Roy,[1,2,3]>
<Roy,[14,15,16]>
<Neha,[1,5,6]>
<Neha,[11,12,13]>
<Jane,[11,8,9]>
```

In above eg., `Roy` and `Neha` is repetitive/duplicate.

Is it possible to hold duplicate keys in `myLHM` ? Because I'm not able to store duplicate keys

No? Then what is the alternative to `LinkedHashMap` to hold duplicate keys?

TIA!

Edit: Those two `Roy` and `Neha` are each the same person

Comment: What do you really want? with duplication or without duplication?

Comment: Ok,  what is `Roy` and `Neha`? Are they String or Key? If key, you need to understand what if key first. `Key` is always unique.

Comment: `Roy` and `Neha` are `String` and I'm using those `String` as `Keys`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any map in the standard java library that can hold duplicate keys, but [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) is an excellent extension to the normal java Collections (and more) done by Google. There you have [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) which can hold several values for the same key (I guess this is what you want in the end). The main benefit I find in using such a library/implementation is that it will take care of everything for you associated with the storage of the values and you don't need to bother about implementing it yourself.

PS: Guava is not just about Collections, which I think it's another Pro why you should check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Add a List of items by key. Whenever you insert, if key was found, just add to the collection. When not found, add a new colelction with current item.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by myself.

What I did is used :

```
LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList>> myLHM = new LinkedHashMap<>() ;
```

Inserted into it as:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> multiDimArray = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add("abc");//some string 1
list.add("lmn");//some string 2
list.add("xyz");//some string 3

multiDimArray.add(list);
myLHM.put("abc"/*use your variable OR pass value like myList.get(position)*/,multiDimArray);
```

Fetched / Retrieved values as:

```
List tempNames=new ArrayList();
Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = myLHM.keySet().iterator();
while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
     tempNames.add(myVeryOwnIterator.next());
}

ArrayList<ArrayList> tempArrayList = new ArrayList();
for (int i=0;i<tempNames.size();i++){
    tempArrayList.addAll(myLHM.get(tempNames.get(i)));
}

String item = null; int year = 0; int amount = 0; 
for (int i=0;i<tempArrayList.size();i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<tempArrayList.get(i).size();j++){
        if(j==0){
           item = (String) tempArrayList.get(i).get(j);
           item = item.replaceAll("\\s", "_");
           } else if (j==1){
           year = Integer.valueOf(tempArrayList.get(i).get(j).toString());
           } else if (j==2){
           amount = Integer.valueOf(tempArrayList.get(i).get(j).toString());
           } else {
           Log.e("Problem","for loop error");
           }
    }
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO ch // my insert query...
    VALUES(" +"'" + item +"'," + year +"," + amount +"," + id +");");
}
```

Comment: You should accept this answer as the correct answer so the question has an accepted answer.